# How to count the number of metrics sent to Datadog over a 24 hour period?

Tags: monitoring, dashboard, datadog

I have a situation where I'm trying to count the number of files loaded into the system I am monitoring. I'm sending a "load time" metric to Datadog each time a file is loaded, and I need to send an alert whenever an expected file does not appear. To do this, I was going to count up the number of "load time" metrics sent to Datadog in a 24 hour period, then use anomaly detection to see whether it was less than the normal number expected. However, I'm having some trouble finding a way to consistently pull out this count for use in the alert.

I can't use the count_nonzero function, as some of my files are empty and have a load time of 0. I do know about .as_count() and count:metric{tags}, but I haven't found a way to include an evaluation interval with either of these. I've tried using .rollup(count, time) to count up the metrics sent, but this call seems to return variable results based on the rollup interval. For instance, if I compare intervals of 2000 and 4000 seconds, I would expect each 4000 second interval to count up about the sum of two 2000 second intervals over the same time period. This does not seem to be what happens at all - the counts for the smaller intervals seem to add up to much more than the count for the larger one. Additionally some rollup intervals display decimal numbers as counts, which does not make any sense to me if this function is doing what I thought it was.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I'd really appreciate any new ideas.

Comment: does `count_not_null()` help? ([docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/graphing/functions/count/#count-not-null))

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Count_not_null() counts up the number of load_time metrics appearing at the time of any given "push," which for me is each time one of my files is loaded. That means that I just see a count of 1 graphed across the entire day. If there were a way to count up all of those count_not_nulls() in a 24-hour period, that would be what I was looking for.